# How to take a video with cameraview library on android?

Tags: android, video, camera, camera-view

I'm using this libray natario1.github.io called 'CameraView' .
I'm having problems because I don't have any real example how to take a video . 
I don't know what to set as a File parameter inside camera.takeVideo(file).
Can someone show me a real example please ?